# Edit text within span tag with ID

Tags: jquery, html

I am having trouble with selecting the text within a span tag (this is in a template, I cannot edit the text directly), here is the HTML:

```
<table class="worf">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="brown45">
                <span id="red24">Quantity and Pricing</span>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
<script>
    $('#red24').text('Confirm Your Reservation');
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Are there errors on your console?  There is nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: The script in this form should be put right before the ending of `body`

Comment: @JamesMontagne likely that code occurs before the `span`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap jQuery code in a [`$(document).ready()` function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#red24').text('Confirm Your Reservation');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Rookie mistake that I think everyone still ends up making at some point :|

Answer (score 0):

**Allways when the document is ready.**

I think it'd be the best to use .html() you can use it just for a add text :

```
$('#red24').html('whathever');
```

or it'd be the best if you prefer to make it visible or with another style or class for instance :

```
$('#red24').html('<p class="foo"><b>Confirm Your Reservation</b></p>');
```